# How to get Grails not to escape html tags generated by CK Editor

Tags: grails, ckeditor, gsp

This question was asked and answered in 2012.  Unfortunately, none of the answers work with Grails 3.3.8 and the Fields plugin.  I tried ${raw(value)} and whatever I could find.  It still shows things like <b>Hello </b> <em>world</em>.  ${raw(value)} is recommended in the latest Grails documentation here

I'm stuck and will appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is how one does it:
First, you need Unbescape.  Add this to build.gradle:

> compile "org.unbescape:unbescape:1.1.6.RELEASE" // to unbescape html

Next do grails create-tag-lib Unbescape.  Here's your whole tag lib class:

```
    import org.unbescape.*
    import org.unbescape.html.*

    class UnbescapeTagLib {

        static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'text']
        //static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName: [taglib:'none']]
        static final namespace = 'ubs'

        def unescape = {attrs, body ->
            out << HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(body.call().toString())
        }
    }
```

Now create a directory called 'show' and inside that a directory called 'description'.  This is of course in your views directory for the particular domain object. Description is the name of the field.  Inside the directory 'description' create a file called _displayWidget.gsp.  This is what the file looks like:

```
    <ubs:unescape>${raw(value)}</ubs:unescape>
```

Calling the raw function on value returns a org.grails.taglib.TagBodyClosure object which is passed to your tag lib.  That's why you have to do a call on the body and turn the result to a String in your tag lib.

This is easy to implement if one knows how to do it, but finding out how to do it was not easy.  The documentation is not good.  The Fields plugin really complicated things a lot.  Before Fields, this was easy to do.